# @ContentChildren doesn't find any elements

Tags: angular

So I'm creating a custom input-group for my design system and I need to check if a ng-content exists to render it's parent element but I can't seem to make @ContentChildren to find my ng-content element.
BTW: ng-content does project correctly my element

I'm currently on angular 14

This is my current attempt (I'm basically trying to copy what angular material does).

```
// directive
@Directive({ selector: '[InputHint]' })
export class InputHintDirective {}

// component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'input-group',
    templateUrl: './.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./.component.scss'],
})
export class InputGroupComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(InputHintDirective)
    _hintChildren: QueryList<InputHintDirective>;

    constructor() {}
}

// input group html

    <div
        class="text-brandGray mb-1 flex items-center justify-start text-sm"
        *ngIf="_hintChildren.length"
    >
        <div class="group ml-2 block cursor-pointer">
            <div class="relative flex items-center">
                <span
                    class="flex h-4 w-4 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-brandBlack text-white"
                >
                    ?
                </span>
                <div
                    class="max-w-96 absolute ml-5 hidden min-w-max rounded-md border border-brandBorder bg-white px-1 text-gray-700 group-hover:block"
                >
                    <ng-content select="[InputHint]"></ng-content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

// using the input group component
<input-group class="col-span-2">
    <span InputHint>First Name</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" />
</input-group>
```

Comment: has you forgot add the directive to the module?

Comment: @Eliseo that was it... Had on a shared module and forgot to actually export the directive. TYSM